# Interacting with Other Apps: onActivityResult method not being called Android

Tags: android

I wish that when I click on the apply button firstapp, opens secondapp thus the data passed the press: What did I do wrong?

Secondapp is called but it print null.

App1

```
package pkg.firstapp;
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_START_APP = 12345;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PackageManager manager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                try {
                    Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("pkg.secondapp");
                    if (i != null)
                    {
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        i.putExtra("key1", "value1");
                        i.setFlags(0);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_START_APP);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get String from Intent, you should call `getIntent().getStringExtra("key1");` in `onCreate`. `onActivityResult` is called in first Activity after finishing second. Read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for more info

Comment: I just read this article before, but something is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult` is called in the activity which started other activity for result.

In order to get the data you're sending, in the second activity's onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String value1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("key1");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hristo Stoyanov, now the apps work very well... therefore onActivityResult function, with associated controls, is no longer needed: how do I make the checks on the data being passed to me?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.

Comment: I tried it with your code and the two applications work, thank you. I commented on the onActivityResult function and applications continue to function. what is wrong in onActivityResult function? It is equal to the guide site https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html whith the example  pickContact().
I'm sorry for my english, is clear the question now?

Comment: If you finish() the second app , the result will be returned to your first app in this method.

Comment: The secondapp must not return firstapp data in my case.
I thought onActivityResult (...) in secondapp needed to filter requests through requestCode parameter.